# Are Android contacts viewable through any Google online service?

Tags: android, google-contacts

I lost my Android phone. I had it logged in my Google account and most of my contacts were saved on that account (I believe, because every time I would add a new one, it asked me for a "contact type" and I chose "mymail@gmail.com").

I really need to recover them. I'm not really sure it was synchronized with any Google online service, but if so, where can I access it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Google takeout](https://www.google.com/takeout/?pli=1) should let you do it, as would the [contacts page under gmail](https://www.google.com/takeout/?pli=1). A new phone under the same account would sync it too.

In addition, [android device manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) should let you locate or wipe your phone remotely

Answer (score 6):

Have you checked Google contacts? http://contacts.google.com/  If you synced to google, you should see your contacts there.

There's no guarantee they're all there. Sometimes you end up adding to the phone, not to Google. But you should see some. You can also download a few ways, including spreadsheet, or vCards.

Answer (score 2):

You can get to your contacts here if you are logged in:

https://www.google.com/contacts/